# Problemas com assincronia do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks, assincronismo

Olá, estou tendo problemas com o processo assíncrono do JavaScript. Preciso que a função   *deleteRoom* seja executada antes da condição IF abaixo dela. Poderiam me ajudar?

Estas funções estão em arquivos diferentes.

**DECLARANDO DELETE ROOM**

```
export function deleteRoom (roomID) {
  let isDeleted = false

  const dbRef = ref(database)
  remove(child(dbRef,`rooms/${roomID}`)).then(()=>{
    isDeleted = true
  })
  
  return isDeleted
}
```

**CHAMANDO DELETE ROOM**

```
import {deleteRoom} from '../hooks/useRoom'

const {isDeleted} = deleteRoom(roomID)

if(isDeleted === true){
      handleUseToast('success', 'Sala deletada!')
      navigate('/')
}else if(isDeleted === false) {
      console.log(isDeleted)
      alert('Permissão Negada!')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema e gostaria de comentar a solução para caso alguém um dia tenha esse problema.

Eu estava importando o resultado da função deleteRoom usando {} (responsável por pegar um valor específico do return, mas era justamente isso que estava causando o erro.

para resolver alterei esta linha de código

```
const {isDeleted} = deleteRoom(roomID)
```

por esta

```
let isDeleted = deleteRoom(roomID)
```